# Negative number in frames after decode with mediacodec

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-mediacodec

I am working on Android app with OpenCV, I am new with MediaCodec.
In my project I need to decode video and save the incoming frames into OpenCV matrix.

I look over [This example.](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest.java.txt)

I tried to test the example, but without success.

My problem is that I have got a negative number from the buffer to the int array.

This is the function that doesn't work:

```
       public void saveFrame(String filename) throws IOException {

       GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
           mPixelBuf);
       mPixelBuf.rewind();

       int pixelCount = mWidth * mHeight;
       int[] colors = mColorSwapBuf;
       mPixelBuf.asIntBuffer().get(colors);
       for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
           int c = colors[i];
           colors[i] = (c & 0xff00ff00) | ((c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) | ((c & 0x000000ff) << 16);
       }

       BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
       try {
           bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
           Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);
           bmp.recycle();
       } finally {
           if (bos != null) bos.close();
       }
   }
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: Can you clarify what the failure mode is?  I don't understand what "got a negative number from the buffer to the int array" means.

Comment: Yep, I have the int array "colors" that get the frames from "mPixelBuf" after "mPixelBuf.asIntBuffer().get(colors);". I've got a negative numbers inside the int array(numbers ~ -15916545).

Comment: That's expected.  Each entry in `colors[]` is a 32-bit ARGB value for a single pixel; since alpha will be 255 (fully opaque), all values will have the form 0xff______, which will appear to be negative.  In your example, -15916545 is 0xff0d21ff (255 alpha, 13 red, 33 green, 255 blue).  Java has an annoying lack of unsigned types.  If you want to see values in hex, use `Integer.toHexString()`.  In any event, the test saves 10 frames to /sdcard/; you should be able to pull the PNGs off and view them.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of it! and I saw the images after I'm saving them. I just don't understand the numbers.